# Why won't the contents of the API be displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, api, debugging

I'm trying to display contents of an API but for some reason I'm getting an error in the console that says `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null` which sort doesn't make sense to me because I've set to `innerHTML = <p>${this.items[i]}</p>`.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?  If you need more information, please let me know.

Here's my html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="baseball">
    <h1>test</h1>
</div>

<script type="application/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        console.log("document is loaded");

        var baseballStats = new BaseballStats();

        baseballStats.init("https://statsapi.mlb.com/api/v1/people/660670/stats?stats=byDateRange&season=2018&group=hitting&startDate=&endDate=&leagueListId=mlb_milb", true);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my javascript

```
class BaseballStats {
  constructor() {
    this.totalItems = 0;
    this.list = document.querySelector("baseball");
  }

  init(url, bool) {
    this.bool = bool;

    var that = this;

    console.log(url);

    fetch(url)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data.stats);

        that.data = data;

        if (this.bool) {
          that.items = that.data.stats;
          this.totalItems = that.items.length;

          console.log("about to loop");

          for (var i = 0; i < this.totalItems; i++) {
            var listNode = document.createElement("LI");

            listNode.innerHTML = `<p>${this.items[i]}</p>`;
            console.log("did it reach here");

            this.list.appendChild(listNode);
          }
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: `querySelector('baseball');` is looking for a tag like `<baseball>` whereas you have a div with a *class*. Simply add a `.` to your query selector

Comment: @SterlingArcher omg... I've been stuck on this all day and this is all it was.... thank you!  I'm so angry at myself lol

Answer (score 0):

Try to console.log the list variable. You will see it's null. You're treating this variable as an object, but the content of the variable is null.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the BaseballStats' `list` member is null. This is because you're misusing `document.querySelector` - it selects in the same way as CSS, so to select an element with a class you need to use the `.` selector - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp.
You are selecting for `'baseball'` however, which means it is trying to find an element with the tag name `<baseball>`. Change this to `'.baseball'` and it will work

Comment: yep, it works.  But I'm getting `[object Object]` (before nothing displayed) to appear in the view so it looks like I have other minor issue

Comment: The JavaScript template literal (``${}``) does implicit `.toString()` conversions on templated variables. To display the contents of an object as a string, as you are trying to do, one solution might be `JSON.stringify(yourObject)`